# Change product link on archives pages for a specific product category in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, hook-woocommerce

I would like to change product link in shop page using woocommerce web hooks for a specific product category.

I know how remove product link with `woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item` hook, but I would like to change the product link in shop page for a specific category.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer . Yes It was correct and I accept your answer

Comment: I do it right now thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated:** The below functions will replace the product link and add to cart link by a custom one on shop and archives pages for a defined product category.

You will need to define the replacement custom link and the product category 2 times for each in this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'customizing_loop_product_link_open', 9 );
function customizing_loop_product_link_open() {
    global $product;

    // HERE BELOW, replace clothing' with your product category (can be an ID, a slug or a name)
    if( has_term( array('clothing'), 'product_cat' )){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'custom_link_for_product_category', 10 );
    }
}

function custom_link_for_product_category() {
    global $product;

    // HERE BELOW, Define the Link to be replaced
    $link = $product->get_permalink();

    echo '<a href="' . $link . '" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link">';
}

// Changing the link on the button add to cart in Shop and archives pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'change_loop_add_to_cart_button_link', 10, 2 );
function change_loop_add_to_cart_button_link( $button, $product  ) {

    // HERE BELOW, replace 'clothing' with your product category (can be an ID, a slug or a name)
    if( has_term( array('clothing'), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ){
        // HERE BELOW, Define the Link to be replaced
        $link = $product->get_permalink();
        $button_text = __( "View product", "woocommerce" );
        $button = '<a class="button add_to_cart_button" href="' .  . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';
    }
    return $button;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).

Tested and works

Comment: great . I tested and it was correct